# What do the keys represent in the array returned by Doctrine 2's getScheduledEntityUpdates() function?

Tags: doctrine-orm, unit-of-work

In Doctrine 2, the UnitOfWork object has a getScheduledEntityUpdates method which returns an array of all entities which are scheduled to be updated. The keys of this array seem to be enormous hexadecimal numbers like `[000000000fa3298000000000d03645f6]`. What do these keys represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These keys are the object hashes of the objects that are stored in [the identity map in the unit of work](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1311-L1343).

You can get the object hash of an object by using [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php):

```php
$object = new \stdClass();

var_dump(spl_object_hash($object));
```

The ORM keeps a list of all object hashes and entity identifiers (hashed) for performance reasons. For example, calling `$em->persist($object)` multiple times won't cause any operations because `$object` is [looked up in the identity map](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1358-L1362) very quickly.

Also, if you call `$em->find('My\Entity', 123)` multiple times, [the identity map is used to find objects that are already in memory](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L2765-L2784).